# What is the difference between "copy something onto a piece of paper" and "copy something out onto a piece of paper"?

Tags: word-usage, difference

What is the difference between *copy something onto a piece of paper* and *copy something out onto a piece of paper* speciically by hand. For example:

> We were told to **copy** a few passages from the book **onto** a piece of paper.
>
> We were told to **copy out** a few passages from the book **onto** a piece of paper.

Comment: Have you done a little research? copy out - copy very carefully and as ACCURATELY as possible [TheFreeDictionary] or copy out - to write something again EXACTLY as it has been written [MacMillan]

Comment: @RubioRic I think that's right. "Copy" could be any little word or phrase, "copy out" sounds like a job to get a longer text exactly right. In the given context, though, I don't see any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the specific example used in the question, either *copy* or *copy out* could be used.

However, the use of [**copy out**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/copy%20out) has a specific meaning:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   : to write down (words that one is hearing or reading)
>   // Are you *copying* all of this *down*?
>   // I *copied out* the equations on a piece of paper.

In short, when you *copy out* something, you generally copy it in real time (simultaneously). You are copying it while listening to it or reading it.

On the other hand, to simply *copy* something (without *out* or *down*) can be used to create a duplicate of something without regard to time. Although, generally, to do something like copy a book would involve a series of time-separated *copying-down* sessions.

So, this would be fine:

> ✔ I *copied* the book.

But these would sound strange, mainly because a book is so long that it would not be a quick or one-session task:

> ✘ I *copied out* the book.
>   ✘ I *copied down* the book.

To clarify the distinction even further:

> ✔ I *copied* the book by *copying* each page.
>   ✔ I *copied* the book by *copying out* each page.
>   ✘ I *copied out* the book by *copying out* each page.
>   ✘ I *copied out* the book by *copying* each page.

---

To add to this, the verb also makes a difference. You could say the following (the first being more common):

> ✔ I *wrote down* what I'd heard earlier in the day.
>   ✔ I *wrote out* what I'd heard earlier in the day.

But you would generally not say any of the following:

> ✘ I *wrote* what I'd heard earlier in the day.
>   ✘ I *copied out* what I'd heard earlier in the day.
>   ✘ I *copied down* what I'd heard earlier in the day.
>   ✘ I *copied* what I'd heard earlier in the day.

Those aren't strictly wrong, but they're uncommon.